# AWS Elastic Beanstalk logs not sorting

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, logging, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I can't figure out about a problem on Elastic Beanstalk, in production. Checking logs I undersood that there is an AWS Environment variable mistake, at time that value was "database-1" (it is a variable used to connect it to postgres database on RDS), thus i change name to "dbpostgres" (my real name of postgres db").
But I have other problems. Thus, when I ask "last 100 rows logs" I obtain this (check through the link):

https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-853396293241.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/resources/environments/logs/tail/e-wybtbxb82p/i-0a91dd317597768ba/TailLogs-1591203234090.out?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200603T165355Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIKOSE77CLMRUGX3Q%2F20200603%2Fus-east-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=dc2df9dca08179285ee23270978fdb09c2c57375fbc8343825bedf01a306e3df

As you can see, I still have problem abiut "error: database "database-1" does not exist", as my last environment variables. Reading more on console log, I understood that there are different logs during the time and not in order! For example I have a log for the deploy done at 10:00, another one at 14:00, another one at 11:00, another one at 17:00, another one at 16:00.. How I can check my current problem? Why logs are not in order? I need just the logs of the new deploy, not the older one!

Comment: The link does not work. ALl the logs for all the deployments are stored in same files. So you always get mixut of them.

Comment: In log file there are these errors
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-03T16_33_47_604Z-debug.log


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-03T10_54_59_485Z-debug.log

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-03T11_11_40_301Z-debug.log

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-04T00_46_37_363Z-debug.log

In different times of the day as you can see in date

Comment: I cann't access it. I get access denied. its only for your account. Maybe can post somewhere else?

Comment: It is too long. But I edited comment with some logs. As you can see above, there are every logs done in all the deployment without any order